# How do I split string by underscore but ignore a certain char

Tags: c#, .net-core

I have a file with the name Starforce.MeridianService_badmin_batxtatptx2_1_2021.07.18-01.24.18.3762.txt. I want to Split('_') by underscore delimiter such that expected result should be:

```
0 = Starforce.MeridianService
1 = badmin
2 = batxtatptx2_1
3 = 2021.07.18-01.24.18.3762
```

I need batxtatptx2_1 to remain unsplit or ignored by the delimiter.

But actual result is

```
0 = Starforce.MeridianService
1 = badmin
2 = batxtatptx2
3 =1
```

Comment: what is the rule on how to split?

Comment: Just join the 3rd and 4th items in the split array with an underscore again...

Comment: @MarioVernari, I want to still split based on _ but I have to keep batxtatptx2_1 together as one string in the array. Currently Split('_') basically splits anywhere it sees an _

Comment: @D_One that is clear, but is that string a known constant or the original string may contains other words that should not broken? for instance, may we consider that a "number alone" (the "1" in your example) should be considered as the suffix of the previous segment, hence the rule on how to split correctly?

Comment: @MarioVernari, It is a suffix of the original string, and it is not a constant. It can have variations but all in this format. For example batxtatptx2_1, batxtatptx2_2, batxtatptx2_3

Comment: In that case, I suggest you use at least two steps to extract the information from the string. First take the time stamp at the end of the string. (Throw away the '.txt' of course.) Then use the overloaded Split function on the remaining front part of the string to split on underscore with no more than three results. This will then give you the three first elements. This assumes that the two first elements can never have underscore.

Comment: If you have created a solution, you can post an answer yourself, and maybe get some upvotes.